# how do i reference my JLabel message in the buttonhandler?

Tags: button, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield, rgb

basically! i need to change the colour of a message originally set to red, using jtextfields, all the code is done except the bit that changes the colour because i dunno how to reference the message. i know it needs to go in the @overide action performed bit but its saying it doesn't recognise what 'message' is, I've tried  message.setForeground(new Color(a, b, c)); but yeah, any help with what to do here would be great, thanks.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



public class CE203_2016_Ex1 extends JFrame {

    JTextField tred, tgreen, tblue;

    public CE203_2016_Ex1() {

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();       //creates panels for the boxes that will hold the rgb values
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        tred = new JTextField("Red", 10);
        tgreen = new JTextField("Green", 10);             //creates boxes for rgb values
        tblue = new JTextField("Blue", 10);

        panel1.add(tred);
        panel1.add(tgreen);                            //adding jtextfields to panels
        panel1.add(tblue);

        add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH); //adding panels to frame
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel message = new JLabel("hello");  //text
        message.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));     //original text set to red

        JButton goButton = new JButton("Change");       //adds button to change colour
        panel1.add(goButton);
        panel2.add(message);
        goButton.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler(this));
    }

    class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        private CE203_2016_Ex1 theApp;

        public ButtonHandler(CE203_2016_Ex1 theApp) {
            this.theApp = theApp;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tred.getText());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tgreen.getText());
            int c = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tblue.getText());


        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame app = new CE203_2016_Ex1();
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setSize(700, 700);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the message label in your App. That means you'll have to make the JLabel message a field of your app and then add a getter to retrieve it. This way anything that has access to your app can also access the message label.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



public class CE203_2016_Ex1 extends JFrame {

    JTextField tred, tgreen, tblue;
    JLabel message;

    public CE203_2016_Ex1() {

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();       //creates panels for the boxes that will hold the rgb values
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        tred = new JTextField("Red", 10);
        tgreen = new JTextField("Green", 10);             //creates boxes for rgb values
        tblue = new JTextField("Blue", 10);

        panel1.add(tred);
        panel1.add(tgreen);                            //adding jtextfields to panels
        panel1.add(tblue);

        add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH); //adding panels to frame
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        message = new JLabel("hello");  //text
        message.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));     //original text set to red

        JButton goButton = new JButton("Change");       //adds button to change colour
        panel1.add(goButton);
        panel2.add(message);
        goButton.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler(this));
    }

    public JLabel getMessageLabel() {
        return message;
    }

    class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        private CE203_2016_Ex1 theApp;

        public ButtonHandler(CE203_2016_Ex1 theApp) {
            this.theApp = theApp;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tred.getText());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tgreen.getText());
            int c = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tblue.getText());
            theApp.getMesssageLabel().setForground(new Color(a, b, c));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame app = new CE203_2016_Ex1();
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setSize(700, 700);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The important parts are:

```
JTextField tred, tgreen, tblue;

// Added field message for later use
JLabel message;

public CE203_2016_Ex1() {
```

.

```
// Enables you to get the message label from your app later on
public JLabel getMessageLabel() {
    return message;
}

class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
```

.

```
int c = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tblue.getText());
// Gets the message label from your App and sets its foreground color
theApp.getMesssageLabel().setForground(new Color(a, b, c));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the variable `message` from outside of its [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) since you declared the JLabel from within the constructor it can only be accessed by the constructor. so you want to declare the JLabel outside of the constructor the same as you have done with the JTextFields also I would recommend making it `private` for this application.

Comment: thanks! I've done it now! all i had to do was make a Jlabel outside like i did with the text fields like you said, and then rename it to message=new JLabel inside like i did with the textfields